# Google Compute Engine User provided OS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Google is charging for Windows OS on its compute engine.
I see there is an option for Free OS which has a User Provided OS. This will reduce the cost of instance.
What is the way to add Windows OS on compute engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bring your own Windows (Server) license into Compute Engine at the time of writing. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/) for more details.

Comment: So you will have to pay for Windows OS and cannot get you own license!!

Comment: The cost of the Windows licence is rolled into the per-hour instance pricing, so you pay as you go. Part of the reason that you cannot import your own licence is actually Microsoft licensing in general being difficult - I believe that they would require you to run the OS on a dedicated host, and Google Cloud does not supported dedicated hosts.

Comment: So what does the term Or User Provided OS mean in OS/Software list box?

Comment: When I launch an instance from the Cloud Console, it offers a list of OS images (comprising Debian, CentOS, CoreOS, Ubuntu, RHEL, SUSE, Windows Server). It doesn't provide an option for a user-provided OS. Where do you see this option?

Comment: Not when I login and select OS but when I open the price calculator it lists **Free: Debian, CentoOS ... or User Provided OS**